# Kotlin: How can I call super's extension function?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, extension-function

How can I call a super's extension function?

For example:

```
open class Parent {
    open fun String.print() = println(this)
}

class Child : Parent() {
    override fun String.print() {
        print("child says ")
        super.print() // syntax error on this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though the `print()` function is defined inside of `Parent`, it belongs to `String`, not to `Parent`. So there's no `print` function that you can call on `Parent`, which is what you're trying to do with `super`.

I don't think there's syntax support for the type of call you're trying to do in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for now, and there is an issue in the kotlin issue-tracker - [KT-11488](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11488)

But you can use the following workaround:

```kotlin
open class Parent {
    open fun String.print() = parentPrint()

    // Declare separated parent print method
    protected fun String.parentPrint() = println(this)
}

class Child : Parent() {
    override fun String.print() {
        print("child says ")
        parentPrint() // <-- Call parent print here
    }
}
```